# TypeError: find_element_by_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser=webdriver.Edge("C:/Users/senem/Desktop/selenium/msedgedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
time.sleep(13)
username=webdriver.Edge.find_element_by_name("username")
password=webdriver.Edge.find_element_by_name("password")


username.send_keys("user")
password.send_keys("password")
time.sleep(10)

browser.close()
```

Hello to everyone. This is error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/senem/PycharmProjects/denemefibo/instagram.py", line 8, in
>
> username=webdriver.Edge.find_element_by_name("username") TypeError: find_element_by_name() missing 1 required positional
> argument: 'name'

Can you help me about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple Explanation

When you create your `browser` variable and set it to `webdriver.Edge`, you are creating an INSTANCE of the class. Just remember that since you've created that `browser`, you need to use that specific `browser` everywhere. So you don't want to keep using `webdriver.Edge`

### More technical explanation

This explanation is in regards to Object Oriented Programming with Python.
Behind the scenes, `find_element_by_name` is actually asking for two arguments (`self, name`). self is automatically passed when you create a new instance, in this case the instance created is `browser`. So when you pass in `username`, you are passing in the SECOND argument because `self` is automatically filled.

Now that we understand this, let's look at your code. You created an instance `browser` but you are not using it. When you attempt to use the method `find_element_by_name` you are using the class directly, not using the instance you made. Since you aren't using the instance, that `self` parameter is no longer fulfilled. So when you pass in `username`, it treats that as the `self`, and you get an error because it still needs `name`.

### Solution

You need to replace `webdriver.Edge` with `browser`.

```
username=browser.find_element_by_name("username")
password=browser.find_element_by_name("password")
```